# There is a way to play an audio from ytdl-core while it's downloading?

Tags: web-audio-api, ytdl

The [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core) has a function that creates a internal.Readable stream that can be piped to a file, example:

```
ytdl(url, { filter: "audioonly"}).pipe(this.fs.createWriteStream(`path/to/file.mp3`));
```

And then, I return the file path after it's completelly downloaded. However, I want to play it while the file is being "downloaded", is there a way to achieve that?